# What is the best way to count values for a series of dates and then graph it in python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, excel-formula

I'm getting started using python and pandas, and need to create a graph with dates along the bottom, and the frequency of four events at each date: a count of diagnoses; diagnosis if during quarantine; diagnoses NOT in quarantine; and a final count quarantine ended without diagnosis. The essential data looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

data = [{'diag': False, 'diagDate': np.nan, 'QStart': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 20), 'QEnd': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 10)},\
   {'diag' : True, 'diagDate': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 11), 'QStart': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 10), 'QEnd': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 24)},\
       {'diag' : True, 'diagDate': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 11), 'QStart': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 1), 'QEnd': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 14)},\
           {'diag' : True, 'diagDate': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 11), 'QStart': np.nan, 'QEnd': np.nan},\
          {'diag' : False, 'diagDate': np.nan, 'QStart': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 20), 'QEnd': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 11)}]

rng1 = pd.date_range('2015-02-24', periods=5, freq='D')
df_counts = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng1})
```

In Excel, I would create a column of dates, and then use each dates as part of a sumproduct to tests each row in the data table for the various conditions. The total diagnosis at each date would look something like:

```
=sumproduct(--(dataTable!diag_value = "True"),--(countTable!date_index = dataTable!diagDateColumn))
```

I'm not sure if this is the right approach when using python / pandas. If yes, then I can easily create a DataFrame with relevant dates, like so:

```
rng1 = pd.date_range('2020-12-09', periods=7, freq='D')
df_counts = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng1})
```

What I cannot work out how to do is use the dates from the row of this new table as a condition to count values in the other dataframe? The output should be:

```
    Date          Cases   CasesinQ       CasesNotinQ       Qended
0   2020-12-09    0       0              0                 0
1   2020-12-10    0       0              0                 1
2   2020-12-11    3       1              2                 1
3   2020-12-12    0       0              0                 0
```

I would hope this table would be a good dataframe for plotting (? - it would be my first plot with python).

I've tried len and count, but they do not pass each row value (Date) to count the frequency of how often it appears in the data dataframe.

Comment: this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37598665/how-to-plot-a-value-counts-in-pandas-that-has-a-huge-number-of-different-counts

Comment: That is indeed another way to think about it! So, IIUC, I probably should be using something like a groupby with dt.date to create a series instead of listing dates as a first step, then create other series with the other conditions - I guess by creating a new column testing the logic on each row; and finally merging it all together by date. Does that sound about right? What if, in my real data, there is no case on a specific day?